# pip -V and pip show pip get different version number?

Tags: python, pip

The following two commands show different version number.

```
bash-4.2$ python -m pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /apps/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

bash-4.2$ python -m pip show pip
Name: pip
Version: 21.2.2
Summary: The PyPA recommended tool for installing Python packages.
Home-page: https://pip.pypa.io/
Author: The pip developers
Author-email: distutils-sig@python.org
License: MIT
Location: /apps/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires:
```

And it showed "Requirement already up-to-date" when I tried to upgrade?

```
bash-4.2$ python -m pip install --upgrade pip --timeout=90
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /apps/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

The site packages directory has three pip directories.

```
bash-4.2$ ls -l /apps/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages | grep pip
drwxr-xr-x. 12 .... ....    4096 Aug  3 12:53 pip
drwxr-xr-x.  2 .... ....     130 Aug  3 11:44 pip-21.2.2.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x.  2 .... ....     154 Aug  3 12:53 pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg-info
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce (Python 3.9, on a Mac) (I do not have an egg-info file)

Comment: I found in the system log that `python -m pip install --upgrade pip --timeout=90` was run during provisioning and it got timeout. This may have caused the issue.